# R can't fit a quadratic equation by resulting an error: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, polynomials

I have a simple dataset:

```
x <- c(1.053848,1.054189,1.054529)
y <- c(0.0137554979,0.0006841939,0.0007282808)
```

Let fit a parabola to `y`

```
ypoly <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
```

I'd like to get the constant ***a*** in the formula:

```
y = ax^2 + bx + c
```

so I type `summary(ypoly)$coefficients[3, 1]` and get this error:

```
Error in summary(ypoly)$coefficients[3, 1] : subscript out of bounds
```

because of

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x         I(x^2)  
      25.17       -19.13           NA
```

[Check this fitting output on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit%20%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath:%7B1.053848,0.0137554979%7D,%20%7B1.054189,0.0006841939%7D,%20%7B1.054529,0.0007282808%7D%2F%2F%5D%7D%20to%20a%20polynomial%20of%20degree%20%5B%2F%2Fnumber:2%2F%2F%5D)

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the design matrix for this linear regression, R tells you that it is computationally singular, meaning it doesn't have an inverse.  The closed form expression for OLS is
[image], but you cannot calculate the inverse for this data.  You can see this with,

```
x <- c(1.053848,1.054189,1.054529)
y <- c(0.0137554979,0.0006841939,0.0007282808)
x2 <- x^2
design <- matrix(c(rep(1, 3), x, x2), ncol = 3)
solve(t(design)%*%design)
```

I'm assuming your issue is how close your x values and x^2 values are.  To fix this, you can run this instead.

```
ypoly <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. However I need parabola model of observed data to extract minimum x value. min =-b/2a doesn't work.

Comment: OK. I solved the problem with a second fit by applying `ypoly <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))` after create new data from prediction. So I obtain the error from `ypoly <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))` which was resulting imaginary from previous equation as you mention. Thanks again @smanski.